# Подписка на событие с передачей параметра

Tags: c#, события

Необходимо при подписке на событие (мультикаст) передать некий параметр в само событие. То есть:

```
TestClass.PerfomancePriorityStartAnalysis += Test(param);

public TestClass{
    public override event PerfomancePriorityStartAnalysisEventhandler PerfomancePriorityStartAnalysis 
    {
        add
        {
            PerfomancePriorityHandlers.Add(value);
            Console.Write(Param);
        }
        remove
        {
        }
    }
}
```

То есть вместе с `value` передать дополнительный параметр. Или же внутри `value` свойством передать этот параметр, помимо метода.

Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Базовыми средствами такого не сделать. Нужно передавать параметр отдельно. Например, вы можете инкапсулировать подписку в метод, в нем устанавливать параметр в приватное поле, а в блоке события `add` обращаться к этому полю. Понятно, что такой способ, к сожалению, не гарантирует того, что кто-нибудь не подпишется напрямую (если только событие `PerfomancePriorityStartAnalysis` не сделать приватным).

```
public TestClass
{
    public object Param { get; set; };

    public override event PerfomancePriorityStartAnalysisEventhandler PerfomancePriorityStartAnalysis 
    {
        add
        {
            PerfomancePriorityHandlers.Add(value);
            Console.Write(Param);
        }
        remove
        {
        }
    }
}

public void SubscribePerfomancePriorityStartAnalysis(object prm)
{
    TestClass.Param = prm;
    TestClass.PerfomancePriorityStartAnalysis += Test;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Раз такого не сделать базовыми средствами, Вы не подскажите, нет ли внутри value в событии какого-нибудь уникального идентификатора, по которому можно идентифицировать именно этот handler?

Comment: @Sleeeper а какую задачу вы вообще решаете? Может быть можно пойти другим путем.

Comment: Мне необходимо сопоставть handler с конкретным id, который на серверной части будет идентификатором с словаре.  Подписка у меня клиент-серверная, на сервере сквозь маршала получаю хэндлер клиента, который подписывается и начинаю публикацию. Так вот мне нужно сопоставить этот хэндлер с его уникальным id, программным. Либо, если у хэндлера есть какое-то уникальный поле - взять его за id

Comment: В общем, проблему удалось решить.  Метод на серверной стороне(в моем случае) принимает (TestEventHandler handler), а клиент явно пихает метод, который он подписывает и вторым аргументом id . В распределённом приложении это через прокси, при обычном подходе работает в лоб.